# Closed form of $\int_0^{\pi/2}t^{m-1}\sin^n(t)dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I wonder if it's possible to write the following integral in a closed form
$$I(m,n)=\int_0^{\pi/2}t^{m-1}\sin^n(t)dt\quad\text{with}\quad n,m\in\mathbb{N}$$
in terms of some special function.

I be able to calculate (with Wolfram Mathematica) some of them, for small values of $n$, for example

$$I(m,1)=\int_0^{\pi/2}t^{m-1}\sin(t)dt=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{\pi }\right)^{-m-1} \, _1F_2\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{m}{2}+\frac{3}{2};-\frac{\pi ^2}{16}\right)}{m+1}$$
but not a closed form for any $n$.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Mathematica can deal with integrals of the form $$
\int_0^{\pi /2} {t^{m - 1} \sin (kt){\rm d}t} ,\quad \int_0^{\pi /2} {t^{m - 1} \cos (kt){\rm d}t} .
$$ So you can use the known power formulas ($(7)$ and $(8)$ [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricPowerFormulas.html)).

Comment: The $n=1$ case is already very complicated. What makes you expect a closed form for a general $n$ ?

Comment: Additionally for $n=2$:

$$I(m,2)=\frac{2^{-m-1} \pi ^m \left(-\pi ^2 \, _1F_2\left(\frac{m}{2}+1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{m}{2}+2;-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\right)+2 m+4\right)}{m (m+2)}$$

Comment: K.delafoite I suspect it because Wolfram calculates this integral for several values of $n $ giving a result in terms of the hypergeometric function